# GetPixel create error: Parameter must be positive and < Height

Tags: vb.net

Following code generate the error:

```
For xx = 0 To BP.Width - 1
    For yy = 0 To BP.Width - 1
        Try

            Dim pixelColor As Color = BM.GetPixel(xx, yy)
            Dim lvi As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem

            lvi.Text = pixelColor.Name.ToString
            lvi.BackColor = pixelColor
            lvi.ForeColor = pixelColor
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    Next
Next
```

Comment: the error appears when yy >29

Comment: VBScript IsNot VB6 IsNot VB.NET. Please do not tag spam.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a little typo

> For yy = 0 To BP.**Height**- 1